# How to check user status when login into wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, frontend

Could you please advice me how to check user status upon login?

I have added a new field named `user_flag` in `wp_users` table to control user status. `user_flag` has value of `active` or `deactivate`.

I want to check this field's value when user logs in.

- if value is `active`, then user can proceed login,
- but if value is `deactivate`, then user can not login, and a message will be displayed to notify user that his account is deactivated and he need to contact admin to re-activate account for him to be able to login.

I looked at `wp-login.php` file but had no idea where to write code to check above logic, could you please advice me where to check `user_flag` at login time?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop trying to modify core code and learn to use the pluggable architecture. Also stop modifying the core database tables. You can store additional fields for users in the usermeta table with `add_user_meta` and retrieve them with `get_user_meta`. If you start modifying core code and database tables, you will never be able to upgrade wordpress.

To answer your question, use something like the following in functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', function($user) {
    if (get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_flag', true) == 'active') {
        return $user;
    }
    return new WP_Error('Account Not Active...');
}, 10, 2);
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_authenticate_user